# Find greater number form self in left side and smaller number form self in right side

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Consider an array `a` of `n` integers, indexed from `1` to `n`.

For every index `i` such that `1<i<n`, define:

- `count_left(i)  =` number of indices `j` such that `1 <= j < i` and `a[j] > a[i]`;
- `count_right(i) =` number of indices `j` such that `i < j <= n` and `a[j] < a[i]`;
- `diff(i)        = abs(count_left(i) - count_right(i))`.

**The problem is: given array `a`, find the maximum possible value of `diff(i)` for `1 < i < n`.**

I got solution by brute force. Can anyone give better solution?

Constraint: 3 < n <= 10^5

**Example**

```
Input Array: [3, 6, 9, 5, 4, 8, 2]
Output: 4
Explanation:
diff(2) = abs(0 - 3) = 3
diff(3) = abs(0 - 4) = 4
diff(4) = abs(2 - 2) = 0
diff(5) = abs(3 - 1) = 2
diff(6) = abs(1 - 1) = 0
maximum is 4.
```

Comment: "bruteforce" is somewhat unavoidable, since you know nothing about the numbers in the array you have to examine them all. But what was the complexity of your algorithm? I can think of an algorithm with linear time complexity, and another with quadratic time complexity, and I would call them both brute force.

Comment: My Solution TC is `O(n ^ 2)`. Can you give linear TC solution?

Comment: How have results like `i = 2 ==> 3 or i = 3 ==> 4` been produced?

Comment: i = 2 means A[i] = 6.  For left side n1 = number of left side(1 to i - 1) element is greater than A[i]. So n1 = 0.  For right side n2  = number of right side(i + 1 to n) is less than A[i]. So n2 = 3. Absolute diff is 3

Comment: The description of the problem is unclear. Please provide clarification.

Comment: you can have a solution that in the best case is O(n) and worse case O(n^2), by going throw the array from left to right and for every i walking back (i-1,i-2,i-3...) until you find the first number that is Bigger than J and setting count_left as count_left(J)+1, for count_right do the same process but go from right to left (from n to 1) and check j > i. after you finished do one pass that calculate the diff and saves the index of the biggest

Answer (score 0):

O(nlogn) approach:

Walk through array left to right and add every element to augmented binary search tree (RB, AVL etc) containing fields of subtree size, initial index and temporary rank field. So immediately after adding we know **rank** of element in the current tree state.

```
lb = index - temprank
```

is number of left bigger elements - remember it in `temprank` field.

After filling the tree with all items traverse tree again, retrieving final element rank.

```
rs = finalrank - temprank
```

is number of right smaller elements. Now just get abs of difference of `lb` and `rs`

```
diff = abs(lb - rs) = abs(index - temprank - finalrank + temprank ) = 
      abs(index - finalrank)
```

But ... we can see that we don't need `temprank` at all.
Moreover - we don't need binary tree!

Just perform **sorting** of pairs `(element; initial index)` by element key and get max absolute difference of `new_index - old_index` (except for old indices 1 and n)

```
a      3, 6, 9, 5, 4, 8, 2
old       2  3  4  5  6    
new       5  7  4  3  6
dif       3  4  0  2  0
```

[Python code](https://ideone.com/iziEHR) for concept checking

```
a = [3, 6, 9, 5, 4, 8, 2]
b = sorted([[e,i] for i,e in enumerate(a)])
print(b)
print(max([abs(n-o[1]) if 0<o[1]<len(a)-1 else 0 for n,o in enumerate(b)]))
```